# MySQL UPDATE query not updating all columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

```
update short_url 
  set redirected="2018-08-10 15:07:44", 
  count=count+1 
  where long_val="EF7219D6-606D-409B-BEF1-00FFF9FF713C";
```

---

```
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| short_val  | varchar(8)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| long_val   | varchar(36) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| created    | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| redirected | datetime    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| count      | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The redirected date is updated with this update, but count does not add ?

Comment: note than `NULL + anything` is `NULL`

Comment: Perhaps change the `count` default to 0 instead of making it nullable.

Comment: You should be quoting count in backticks: it's a reserved word so I'm surprised the statement doesn't fail

Comment: Alex K. - thanks, your comment helped me - how do I give you the points? Also, please tell me how you fixed the table view of my original question - I tried but gave up...

Comment: You can accept @spencer7593's detailed answer.  To format, select the block of text and press ctrl+k or click the `{}` icon in the edit toolbar or indent all the lines with 4 spaces.

Comment: @symcbean: `COUNT` is not a MySQL reserved word. Yes, identifiers can be enclosed in backticks.

Comment: A quick Google suggests you're right, it's not a mysql reserved word, but it is in Oracle and transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can test for a NULL value, and replace a NULL with a non-null value, for example ...

```
UPDATE short_url t 
   SET t.redirected = '2018-08-10 15:07:44'
     , t.count = IFNULL( t.count ,0) + 1
--               ^^^^^^^         ^^^
 WHERE t.long_val = '...'
```

If the current value of `count` is NULL, then we will assign a value of `1` to it.

---

Note that most expressions that involve a NULL value will evaluate to NULL.  We can handle NULL values using the `IS NULL` conditional test, the IFNULL() function, the ANSI standards compliant `COALESCE` function, et al.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is make sure the default value of the field 'count' is set to 0 and not NULL

Comment: Forcing an arbitrary value is the wrong solution, even if the OP considers null==0 (which was not stated in the question)